# formatting bash script output (tabs or tables or spaces, make even rows/columns)

Tags: bash

I would like to have even columns. Im trying to use tabs to make even columns but the data is of different sizes so it doesnt always even out. I tried using printf %5s (%10s, etc.) to make each entry a certain width, that didnt really work very well, so I abandoned that idea.

This is what Ive got right now:

this is the header:

```
printf "===DATE=== \t # \t EP \t SLOT \t EXP. TIME \t LOCAL TIME \t DIFFS \t HASH \t HEIGHT \t SHLXPR \t POOLTL \t BSXP \t BPTL \t BLKS \t CPU\n"
```

this is the data:

```
printf "$DATE \t $COUNTER \t $EPOCH \t $LATEST_SLOT \t $LAST_BLOCK_TIME \t $TIME \t $TDIFF \t $LAST_HASH \t $LATEST_BLOCK \t $shelleyLastBlockCount \t $MAJOR_TIP \t $BEHIND_SHELLEY \t $BEHIND_POOLTOOL \t $MULTIBLOCK \t $CPU_USE \n"
```

it comes out looking like this:

```
===DATE===      #    EP   SLOT      EXP. TIME      LOCAL TIME     DIFFS     HASH      HEIGHT    SHLXPR    POOLTL    BSXP      BPTL      BLKS      CPU

2020-01-20      2    38   1020      19:47:37       19:47:37       0s        96e5e     115985    115985    115983    0    -2   0002      23.1
2020-01-20      3    38   1026      19:47:49       19:47:51       -2s       d4281     115986    115986    115986    0    0    0001      0
2020-01-20      4    38   1040      19:48:17       19:48:19       -2s       eabd8     115987    115987    115986    0    -1   0001      10
```

I pad some of the other entries with spaces to keep them even, but you can see at the end it falls off alignment. Sometimes it evens out if entries are long enough.

Comment: if you have tab separated output, pipe it to column (1)

Comment: Alternatively you could use width format specifier with printf `printf "%20s\t%20s\n" "$DATE" "$COUNTER"` to pad it.

Comment: Don't add spaces after `\t`. With `printf` use `%s` in the first parameter when another parameter can have something like `%s`.

Comment: @JamesTomasino -- column says "column: line too long" (printf "yada \t yada \t 13times" | column -c 13) create 13 columns from tabs (is that right?)

Comment: @WalterA sorry, I dont quite understand what you mean.

Comment: don't understand why `printf/format` was abandoned; figure out the max width of each column of data, the amount of space you want between columns, and use those numbers to build the `printf` format; if not sure what the max width of a column of data may be then add some logic to find max column widths (eg, loop through the raw data, find the max length of each column)

Comment: What format is the data in before you read it into the `$DATE`, `$COUNTER` etc. variables?

Comment: @Jon: Don't add spaces after \t : Not a problem, but most people expect a column to start at a tab position (3/6/9 or 8/16/24). You might consider KamilCuk's format specifier.

Comment: @Jon: `printf "$string"` will try to resolve formatting stuff inside `$string`. So start with a formatting string like `printf "%10s %5s %10s\n" "$DATE" "$COUNTER"  "$EPOCH"`.

Comment: @jon column needs every line to terminate in a newline. That means you might need to tack and extra "\n" on your output. Also, try the -t switch for pretty table output.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accumulate results you could use `paste` command for that

`paste <( echo $DATE_RECORDS ) <( echo $COUNTER_RECORDS ) <( echo $EPOCH_RECORDS )`
NOTE: records should be separated new line character.

If you need to print as you go then solutions with static field width (like using printf) are the only option.